# MVCMusicStore Tutorial Album id?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am wondering at where does the program generate the AlbumId?
In the beginning I tried to use SQL Server Compact Edition but the error page said "unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider" blah blah...
I could not continue.

Then I downloaded the whole MVCMusicStore code and added the database to the "App_Data" folder, changed the connectionStrings in the Web.config file. IT WORKS.
I checked the database tables, they have got the IDs set already (AlbumId, GenreId etc).
**DID THEY SET THOSE IDS MANUALLY?**

But then I tried to build a new site based on it. This time I am using the SQL Server Compact Edition, I downloaded the 4.0 version to get it to work.
I am doing the "Details" page...
Let me quote some lines from the tutorial...

"We’ll make the same change to our /Store/Details/[id] URL, and replace our dummy data with a database query which loads an Album whose ID matches the parameter value."

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
 {
    var album = storeDB.Albums.Find(id);

    return View(album);
 }
```

**WHERE IS THE ID FROM?**
The SampleData.cs used to initialize the Albums has not set the id I am sure, here is some piece of code from the SampleData.cs

```
new List<Album>
        {
            new Album { Title = "A Copland Celebration, Vol. I", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Classical"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Copland & London Symphony Orchestra"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
            new Album { Title = "Worlds", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Jazz"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "Aaron Goldberg"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
            new Album { Title = "For Those About To Rock We Salute You", Genre = genres.Single(g => g.Name == "Rock"), Price = 8.99M, Artist = artists.Single(a => a.Name == "AC/DC"), AlbumArtUrl = "/Content/Images/placeholder.gif" },
            ...
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

The column is set as a [Identity Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) in the database. Basically it starts at 1 and with each insert the ID is incremented (that is the default behaviour anyway, it can be customised).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely SQL table has `default` set for this column.